# Best way present and hide UIView on top of UIWindow from NSObject?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, nsobject, uiwindow

I've an NSObject class which handle the locations and in a specific point it shows up a UIView and constantly updates the view and then hides it and vice versa.

I tried a few methods with `addSubview`:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow
[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows.firstObject
```

I've a UILabel on top of this UIView which I updates with some value (distance from point to point), somehow it doesn't updates the view anymore, it shows up once and thats it and it doesn't hides it back.

My code:

```
// Updates the UIView from NSObject class:
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            params[@"distance"] = @(distanceToTrap);
            params[@"TrapType"] = @(trap.getTrapType);
            params[@"TrapID"] = @(trap.getTrapID);

            trapAlarmActivity = [[TrapAlarm alloc] initWithUserInfo:params];
            [trapAlarmActivity setNeedsDisplay];
            [trapAlarmActivity.screenView setNeedsDisplay];

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:trapAlarmActivity];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow setNeedsDisplay];

// The function inside the UIView that updates the UILabel and it somehow doesn't updates anymore
- (void)broadcastLocationChange:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    if (![db isTrapAlarmOpen]) { return; }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (globalTrap == nil) {
            //globalTrap = [db getTrap_trapID:trapID];
            globalTrap = [dbat getTrap_trapID:trapID];
        }


        int distanceToTrap = [db getTrapDistance:globalTrap.getTrapID];

        if (distanceToTrap == 0) {
            CLLocation *originalLocation = kSERVICE_CONTEXT.locationManager.location;
            CLLocation *trapLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:globalTrap.lat longitude:globalTrap.lon];

            distanceToTrap = [trapLocation distanceFromLocation:originalLocation];
        }

        NSLog(@"TRAP ALARM - TRAP DISTANCE TO CAR: %i", distanceToTrap);

        if (stillNotYetKey)
        {
            [self changeMessageBoxWithDistance:distanceToTrap];

            if (distanceToTrap < kFINISH_ALARM_DISTANCE)
                stillNotYetKey = NO;
            else
            {
                if (distanceToTrap > lastDistanceToTrap) {
                    [self finishTrapAlarm];
                }
                else {
                    [self changeMessageBoxWithDistance:distanceToTrap];
                }
            }
        }
        // Check if user exit polygon before passing trap
        if (distanceToTrap > lastDistanceToTrap)
        {
            distanceGrow++;
            if (distanceGrow >= kCOUNTER_FOR_CLOSE_WINDOW_WHEN_DISTANCE_GROW_USER_OUT) {
                [self finishTrapAlarm];
            }
        }
        lastDistanceToTrap = distanceToTrap;
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow setNeedsDisplay];
    });
}

// Function that removes the UIView
- (void)dismiss
{
    [self removeFromSuperview];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow setNeedsLayout];
}
```

I'm I doing something wrong in here?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to simply present and dismiss a view then use `presentViewController` and `dismissViewController` for the same. Frequently changing the  `keyWindow` is not advised.

Comment: Eventually whether its UIView or UIViewController I need it to show from the NSObject class.

Comment: @IdanMoshe You can always setup delegate functions to communicate between the `UIViewController` and the `NSObject` class. showing dynamic content using a `presented UIVIewController` is not much different from what you are doing currently.